# Metodo count() en listas [Python]

Tags: python

Buenas tardes y gracias por leerme. Soy nuevo en Python asi que espero me tengan paciencia :). Tengo una clase "Persona" con 2 atributos (edad y nombre), el cual tiene 6 objetos almacenados en una lista. Deseo contar la cantidad de personas que tienen edad = 22, mediante el método de listas count(). Mi problema está en que no se como "decirle" al programa que quiero que se busque en base a las edades, ya que count solo toma un parametro (el valor que se busca) y no acepta parametros key. ¿Me podrian dar una mano?

Esto es lo que habia intentado

```
class Persona:

    def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
        self.__nombre= nombre
        self.__edad= edad

    def mostrar(self):
        print (f"{self.__nombre}   {self.__edad}")

    def contar(self,lista):
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            print(lista.count(self.__edad == 22))


print("Programa iniciado\n")

# Creación de la lista y de los objetos
lista_personas= []
p1= Persona('Luciano',22)
p2= Persona('Matias',24)
p3= Persona('Andres',23)
p4= Persona('Miguel',20)
p5= Persona('Cristina',24)
p6= Persona('Susana',28)

# Se agregan los objetos a la lista
lista_personas.append(p1)
lista_personas.append(p2)
lista_personas.append(p3)
lista_personas.append(p4)
lista_personas.append(p5)
lista_personas.append(p6)


input("\nContinuar\n")
lista_personas[1].contar(lista_personas) # Cuenta la cantidad de numeros 9 que se encuentran en la lista1
```

Answer (score 1):

Voy a intentar explicar porqué lo que pides no es posible, no directamente sobre `lista_personas` sin modificar la implementación de tu clase (ver solución al final de la respuesta). El método `list.count` es "equivalente" realmente a algo así:

```
def count(lista, valor):
    contador = 0
    for item in lista.
        if item == valor:
            contador += 1
```

Es decir, se usa el operador de igualdad para comparar si cada item de la lista es igual o no al valor pasado a `count`.

Cuando haces:

```
lista.count(self.__edad == 22)
```

lo que le pasas a `count` es un boleano, `True` si la edad de esa persona (la instancia que usas para llamar a `contar`) es 22 o `False` en caso contrario. Por lo tanto siempre tienes 0 de resultado ya que no hay nunca un valor `True` o `False` en la lista, son todos objetos de la clase `Persona`.

La única forma de que el método `cout` funcione es hacer que tu clase determine la igualdad con un entero en base a la edad de la persona implementando el método `__eq__` como mínimo adecuadamente:

```
class Persona:

    def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
        self.__nombre= nombre
        self.__edad= edad

    def mostrar(self):
        print (f"{self.__nombre}   {self.__edad}")

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return other == self.__edad
        elif isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return other.__nombre == self.__nombre and other.__edad == self.__edad
```

Ahora puedes usar `list.count` directamente y no usando un método de la clase lo cual no tiene mucho sentido:

```
print("Programa iniciado\n")

# Creación de la lista y de los objetos
lista_personas= []
p1= Persona('Luciano',22)
p2= Persona('Matias',24)
p3= Persona('Andres',22)
p4= Persona('Miguel',22)
p5= Persona('Cristina',24)
p6= Persona('Susana',22)

# Se agregan los objetos a la lista
lista_personas.append(p1)
lista_personas.append(p2)
lista_personas.append(p3)
lista_personas.append(p4)
lista_personas.append(p5)
lista_personas.append(p6)

print(lista_personas.count(22)) # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

El método `__eq__` es el que usa el operador `==` y por `list.count` por tanto.
 Lo suyo es implementar el resto de métodos de comparación del modelo de datos de Python:

- [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Cierto es que nos podemos plantear con toda razón si establecer que un entero 22 sea considerado igual que un objeto `Persona` con edad 22 no es muy apropiado, y ciertamente no lo es, pero es la única forma de poder aplicar `list.count` directamente sobre tu lista de Personas.

Answer (score 0):

Uso una lista por comprensión y sobre eso llamo el método `count` y el parametro "edad".

```
class Persona:

    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

    def mostrar(self):
        print('{nombre}   {edad}' % (self.__edad, self.__nombre))

    def contar(self, edad=None, lista=[]):
        #              |___ Se me ocurre poner la edad en un
        #                   como un parametro.

        self.conteo = [p.edad for p in lista].count(edad)
        # Guardo el valor en el atributo "conteo".


print("Programa iniciado\n")

# Creación de la lista y de los objetos
lista_personas = []
p1 = Persona('Luciano', 22)
p11 = Persona('Luciano2', 22)
p12 = Persona('Luciano3', 22)
p2 = Persona('Matias', 24)
p22 = Persona('Matias', 24)
p3 = Persona('Andres', 23)

# Se agregan los objetos a la lista
lista_personas.append(p1)
lista_personas.append(p11)
lista_personas.append(p12)
lista_personas.append(p2)
lista_personas.append(p22)
lista_personas.append(p3)

p1.contar(edad=22, lista=lista_personas)
print(p1.conteo)
```

Este programa devuelve: 3